# Creating name pipes and exchanging struct data between c-app and dlang in linux

Tags: c, d

I'm trying in an existing project to replace the present c-coded application GUI with a web GUI using dlang. The application still exists, on OpenSuse 12.3 x32 platform and communicates with the GUI through FIFO pipe's.

The message is a struct created in C and defined in one single .h file globally accessable for all parties in the project.

Now to my problem, I've managed to create a pipe and write to it and from a terminal with "cat " read the contents of the pipe, however when I try to read using pipe-handle in dlang I get a lot of ?-chars and return info that -1 was read from pipe. Any ideas to why "?????" is all I receive 
Code below is first the server

```
import std.range, std.stdio, std.conv;
import core.stdc.string;
import core.stdc.stdio;
import core.sys.posix.sys.stat;
import core.sys.posix.unistd;
import core.sys.posix.fcntl;
import core.sys.posix.sys.stat;

//extern (C) uint read(int, void *, uint);
extern (C) uint write(int, void *, ulong);

struct IOREQ {
    short   fc;         /* function code */
    short   rs;         /* return code */
    short   src;        /* return in fifo-pipe */
 };

int fd = -1;
int freader = -1;
char [1024] rbuf = "";



void main(string[] args) {
int st = mknod("/Users/anders/pipes/4321", S_IFIFO|octal!666,0);
close(st);
fd = open("/Users/anders/pipes/4321", O_WRONLY);
//freader = open("/Users/anders/pipes/4321", O_RDONLY);

char [1024]sbuf;
char [1024]rbuf;        
int res = -1;
sbuf =  "Testing a message in pure text to send to client using a FIFO-pipe\n";
while(1){

    res = write(fd, cast(void *)sbuf, sbuf.sizeof);
    writeln("Wrote data in the pipe, :", res);
    sleep(2);
    sbuf =  "Testing another message in pure text to send to client\n";
}

close(fd);

}
```

Now the client

```
import std.range, std.stdio, std.conv;
import core.stdc.string;
import core.stdc.stdio;
import core.sys.posix.sys.stat;
import core.sys.posix.unistd;
import core.sys.posix.fcntl;
import core.sys.posix.sys.stat;
import core.thread;

extern (C) uint read(int, void *, uint);
//extern (C) uint write(int, void *, ulong);

struct IOREQ {
...
 };

int fd = -1;
int freader = -1;
char [1024] rbuf = "";



void main(string[] args) {
//int st = mknode("/Users/anders/pipes/4321", S_FIFO|0666,0);

freader = open("/Users/anders/pipes/4321", O_RDONLY);
//freader = open("/Users/anders/pipes/4321", O_RDONLY);
if(freader < 0)
{
    writeln("Couldn't open pipe ", freader ); 
}
else
{
    char [1024]sbuf;
    char [1024]rbuf;        

    writeln("Reading data from pipeserver\n");
    int st = read(fd, cast(void *)sbuf, sbuf.sizeof);
    writeln("Done reading, read :", st);
    writeln("Data :\n", sbuf);


        close(freader);
    }
}
```

Comment: If the `read` call returns  `-1` that means something went wrong and you have an error you need to check.

Comment: Oh, and if I try from a terminal to "cat" the pipe the while loop works and I get the message over and over again. dlang code simply breaks out of the loop after first write.

Comment: Figured out that there is some error ( returned -1 ) but I can't see where in the code there might be a problem. Interresting is that cat display the message anyway som it must lay in the pipe waiting to be picked up

Comment: In C you would check if `read` returned `-1` and then print the value of `errno` (or use `perror` or `strerror` to print or get a string). How it's done in D I don't know.

Comment: Have found the problem, SBS as we say in Sweden. I was reading from wrong file/pipe correcting the filehandler in read to freader instead of fd. Also to add 
    import core.stdc.errno; 
    writeln(errno)
gave me output of errorno.
http://www.virtsync.com/c-error-codes-include-errno display what it ment

Comment: write it up as an answer to yourself and you can accept it tomorrow, so anyone who lands here later can read that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have found the problem, SBS as we say in Sweden. I was reading from wrong file/pipe correcting the filehandler in read to freader instead of fd. Also to add import core.stdc.errno; writeln(errno) gave me output of errorno. 
http://virtsync.com/c-error-codes-include-errno display what it ment